# Linq Paging using Skip and Take returning wrong result after first page

Tags: jquery, linq, take

We have a jquery.jtable page that implements paging.  We noticed that the paging is not quite working.  For example, if there are 17 total items, the first page correctly shows 10 and the second shows 7. However, if there is a total of 20 items, the first page show 10 and the second shows only 8.
We are using:

return myQuery.Skip(startIndex).Take(pageSize).ToList()

On the second page, the startindex = 10 and the page size = 10 and as I said above, it is only returning 8.  The culprit seems to be the .Take.  I placed an if statement just above the code with the take as:

```
       if (myQuery.Skip(startIndex).ToList().Count() <= pageSize)
       {
          return myQuery.Skip(startIndex).ToList();
       }
```

On the second pass, the If returns true, since the count and the pagesize are both 10.  The return here does indeed return all 10 rows of the second page.  The concern I have is that if the full myQuery set is large, this could cause resource issues.  Fortunately, this particular table contains a small row count.

Has anyone else encountered this and found a better solution?

Comment: Can you reproduce this with a short but complete program using LINQ to Objects? I'd expect it to be fine... (It's not clear where jquery comes into this, btw. Just because jquery is making the requests doesn't mean it's part of the problem. I would try to isolate the problem as much as you can, removing all extraneous aspects.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you derive startIndex must be the culprit. Try this:

```
return myQuery.Skip((pageNumber - 1 ) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();
```

Edit:

And make sure pageNumber never goes beyond the maximum possible page number.

```
var maxPages = maxRecords / pageSize + (maxRecords % pageSize > 0 ? 1 : 0);
```

So for example you have a method to retrieve only the records you want for a particular page:

```
public List<SomeEntity> GetSomeEntityForPage(int pageNumber, int pageSize)
{
    return myQuery.Skip((pageNumber - 1 ) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList(); 
}
```